# Eclipse screwed with open "initializing connections and drivers" process after playing with JPA facet / all data source explorer connections gone :-(

Tags: eclipse, jpa, toad

after Eclipse was hanging a first time ... I am not sure anymore at which step exactly, but somewhere when trying to `Project->Mouse Context Menu->JPA Tools->Generate Tables from Entities`

- Eclipse (*Kepler Service Release 2*, *4.3.2.M20140221-1700* under *Win 7 64bit*)
- after a restart all my data source explorer connections were gone (> 30) :-(

  - good that I exported most of them, but I removed the passwords and thus the re-import
    is still time-consuming and ugly
- the process `Initializing connections and drivers` never went away again (at least > 15 min and not after stopping this process `Cancel Requested`)
- the import of one foo.xml connections file succeeded, but the 2nd on will always crash Eclipse again with the empty list again
- I did not find my old backup in `<myworkspaye>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity\ServerProfiles.bak`
- even closing the only JPA project and restarting did not help

It may be unrelated, but I removed (obviously unsuccessfully) some earlier installed `Toad Extension Plugin` a long time ago which now throws errors in the `.metadata/.log` (and may have thrown it for some time already):

- megs of logs of this (10 just filled rolled-over log files)
- it also shows two entries `Toad Extension` under `Window Preferences`
- I found similar folders of types `.metadata/.plugins/com.dell.toadext*`, `.metadata/.plugins/com.quest.toadext*` and `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/com.{dell|quest}.*`

```
    !SESSION 2014-12-12 15:12:03.560 -----------------------------------------------
    eclipse.buildId=4.3.2.M20140221-1700
    java.version=1.7.0_25
    java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
    BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=de_DE
    Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.reporting.product -cp
    Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.reporting.product -cp

    This is a continuation of log file D:\.metadata\.bak_0.log
    Created Time: 2014-12-12 15:12:25.921

    !ENTRY com.dell.toadext 4 0 2014-12-12 15:12:25.921
    !MESSAGE Error while initialize metadata model
    !STACK 0
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.quest.toadext.oracle.core.provider.OraTriggerErrorInfoProvider cannot be found by com.dell.toadext.oracle.core_2.0.0.201403131600
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:340)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1212)
        at com.dell.toadext.core.ModelHelper.doCreateOwnedChildrenProviders(Unknown Source)
        at com.dell.toadext.oracle.core.OraModelHelper.createOwnedChildrenProviders(Unknown Source)
        at com.dell.toadext.core.ModelHelper.initOwnedChildrenProviders(Unknown Source)
        at com.dell.toadext.core.ModelHelper.(Unknown Source)
        at com.dell.toadext.oracle.core.OraModelHelper.(Unknown Source)
        at com.dell.toadext.oracle.core.OraclePlatform.createModelHelper(Unknown Source)
        at com.dell.toadext.core.DbPlatform.(Unknown Source)
        at com.dell.toadext.oracle.core.OraclePlatform.(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
        at com.dell.toadext.core.DbPlatformRegistry$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
        at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
        at com.dell.toadext.core.DbPlatformRegistry.loadAllExtensions(Unknown Source)
        at com.dell.toadext.core.AbstractExtensionRegistry.(Unknown Source)
        at com.dell.toadext.core.DbPlatformRegistry.(Unknown Source)
        at com.dell.toadext.core.DbPlatformRegistry.getInstance(Unknown Source)
        at com.dell.toadext.prefs.ToadextPreferences.findNewDefPlatform(Unknown Source)
        at com.dell.toadext.prefs.ToadextPreferences.initializeDefaultPlatform(Unknown Source)
        at com.dell.toadext.ToadextInitializer.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after moving out all the above mentioned `.metadata/.plugin/*toad*` folders the never-ending process went away, but importing db connection profiles more than once is not possible (Eclipse hanging again)

- also the toad extension is not removed this way
- but at least only one such exception in the logs now :-/

I guess I'll run through the complete cycle of installing/setting up a fresh Eclipse install or better workspace :-/

Comment: somehow it did help and work with the old workspace ... **maybe after some clean restart-shutdown cycle?!** (I can't reproduce it anymore and thus it's fine now)